# subset vector and print two elements in a for loop

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a vector `s` and in a 'for loop' I need to print the first two values (1,2) then, (2,3) then (3,4) and so on.

```
s <- c(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)
```

All I can think of is

```
for (i in s) {
  print(i)
}
```

It only print out one element at a time, can someone help with this small code-let.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rollaplly` from library `zoo` with `width = 2` as we need to print 2 elements at a time and we concatenate the elements together with a ",".

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(s, 2, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ","))

#[1] "1,2" "2,3" "3,4" "4,5"
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of a vector, if I have a df$col and want to perform the same function on it, how should I modify it?

Comment: @user3698773 instead of vector put `df$col` i.e `rollapply(df$col, 2, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ","))`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with

```
s <- c(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)
for (i in 1:(length(s)-1)){
  print(paste('(', s[i], ",", s[i+1], ")", sep = ""))
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 1:(length(s)-1)) print(s[c(i:(i+1))])
```

Comment: Thanks, instead of a vector, if I have a df$col and want to perform the same function on it, how should I modify it?

Comment: `for(i in 1:(dim(df)[1]-1)) print(df$col[c(i:(i+1))])` (this is assuming you must use a `for` loop. There are nicer ways of achieving this without it)

Comment: Thanks, please do suggest better ways to achieve it without a for a loop.

Comment: `paste(df$col,lead(df$col))[-dim(df)[1]]` will result in `"1 2" "2 3" "3 4" "4 5"`

Comment: and to make it prettier: `paste0("(",df$col,", ",lead(df$col),")")[-dim(df)[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
sapply(seq_along(s)[-length(s)], function(i) paste(s[i], s[i+1], sep=", "))
[1] "1, 2" "2, 3" "3, 4" "4, 5"
```